# Anyone successfully adopted JaikuEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Are there real world adaptations of JaikuEngine on Google App Engine?
(Question from my boss which wants to use it instead writing our own system)

Answer (score 2):

This is jaikuengine running on AppEngine - https://jaiku.appspot.com/
If you wish to have your own version of jaiku, its pretty straightforward. Check this out- http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I love the App-Engine.  Does your solution need to be hosted on the AppEngine?  If not I would check out [identi.ca](http://identi.ca) which is based on the Open Source [Laconi.ca](http://laconi.ca/trac/)

Answer (score 0):

Does http://www.jaiku.com/ count?